# Ecto insert fails on web post (expected), passes on mix test (unexpected)

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have a controller with a create function that looks like this:

```
def create(conn, %{"data" => refinement_params}) do

    case Repo.insert %Refinement{ refinement_code: refinement_params["refinement_code"], team_name: refinement_params["team_name"], organization_id: conn.assigns[:organization_id]} do
      {:ok, model}        -> json conn, %{refinement_code: model.refinement_code}
      {:error, changeset} -> conn |> send_resp(500, "")
    end    

  end
```

I have a *validate_length(:refinement_code, min: 5)* clause in the changeset of the model. If I post using a web REST tool to the controller with an empty refinement_code, I get a 500 response back as expected.

In the tests for the controller, I have the following:

```
@invalid_attrs %{refinement_code: "", team_name: ""}

test "/api call to create a voting session with creds but invalid data gets an error code", %{conn: conn} do

    organization = Repo.insert! %Organization{domain: "test.com", email: "test.tester@test.com"}

    conn = recycle(conn)
        |> put_req_header("unique_code", organization.unique_code)
        |> put_req_header("domain", organization.domain) 

    conn = post conn, "/api/refinements", data: @invalid_attrs
    assert conn.status == 500        

  end
```

In this case, the *conn.status* is a 200 for some reason. Why is the test incorrectly failing?

Comment: This is confusing - what is incorrectly passing? The test says you'll get an error, and asserts that you get an error. Where is the 200?

Comment: The test is incorrectly failing. I'm expecting the assert to have a 500 since I'm passing bad parameters in.

Comment: can you add the changeset method from your model to the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using the changeset in the controller action, so validations won't be run. I would check the logs for some other reason your web requests are failing.

To make your controller action use the changeset and its validations, you want to use something like this:

```
    changeset = Refinement.changeset(%Refinement{}, refinement_params)
    case Repo.insert(changeset) do
    ....
```

Comment: The reason that the web request was failing was that it actually tried to hit the DB and failed because of its NOT NULL status. I did change the code to what you showed and it worked. Thanks for the answer!